# How to Fix VAR functions in a Switch Statement in Power BI

Tags: switch-statement, powerbi, dax

Newbie here. I'm trying to set up a return value called "Label" based on two criteria in Power BI. We have 23 countries in our company. If they meet 3 specific countries, I then want the label to be called "Cars" as notated below, if they do NOT meet these countries, I then essentially want to give it an alternate label based on my layer 2 name criteria.

The problem is that SOME of these managers also have headcount in these 3 countries that could be Photos or Cameras, but want them to say Cars instead.

It's just not working for me, unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the DAX I am trying to get right:

```
Label =
  VAR _Country = SWITCH(
    TRUE (),
    ActiveHC[Country Name] = "Turkey", "Cars",
    ActiveHC[Country Name] = "Greece", "Cars",
    ActiveHC[Country Name] = "Italy", "Cars",
    Blank()
  )
  VAR _Segment = SWITCH(
    True(),
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Beth", "Corporate",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Joanie", "Corporate",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Dan", "Corporate",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Bill", "Corporate",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Christina", "Corporate",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Steven", "Cars",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Bobby", "Audio",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Matt", "Photos",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Peter", "Photos",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Edward", "Photos",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Joey", "Software",
    ActiveHC[Business Unit] = "Cameras", "Cameras",
    BLANK ()
    )
RETURN IF(ISBLANK(_Country), _Segment, _Country)
```

I essentially want to be able to create a table that says this:

```
Label   Count
Cars    7
Imaging 1
Audio   1
Corporate   1
Software    1
Photos  1
```

I also want to use the field as a filter and also add this calculated column in a table with other data as a records export.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks so much!!!

![Data Sample]https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2rF9.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a calculated column in your model like so:

```
Country Name Filtered =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    ActiveHC[Country Name] = "Turkey", "Cars",
    ActiveHC[Country Name] = "Greece", "Cars",
    ActiveHC[Country Name] = "Italy", "Cars",
    BLANK ()
)
```

Then, create another calculated column called segment:

```
Segment =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Beth", "Corporate",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Joanie", "Corporate",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Dan", "Corporate",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Bill", "Corporate",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Christina", "Corporate",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Steven", "Cars",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Bobby", "Audio",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Matt", "Photos",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Peter", "Photos",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Edward", "Photos",
    ActiveHC[Layer 2] = "Joey", "Software",
    ActiveHC[Business Unit] = "Cameras", "Cameras",
    BLANK ()
)
```

Combine these columns into another, call it blended or something:

```
Blended =
IF ( ISBLANK ( Table[Country Name Filtered] ), Table[Segment], Table[Country Name Filtered] )
```

Now you can reference these values in a slicer or measure much easier:

```
Count Values :=
COUNT ( Table[Blended] )
```

So you would basically create a table or matrix visual using Table[Blended] as your row values and [Count Values] as your measure.

Not an elegant solution but it will work.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks, Stelio. The problem is this doesn't count for the 3 country names taking priority over the other labels. As I mentioned above, some of those managers (Layer 2 names) have people in those countries so some people may be Cars AND camera, but if the country is say Italy, I would want it to say CARS and not Camera. That's why I tried building in logic to say "if the country is one of these 3 names then say "CARS", otherwise say "Segment" -- that's what I was trying to do with the VAR functions. There has to be some logic to make it work properly. Thanks re!

Comment: @SirGalatsi can you post a picture of your data model in the original post please?

Comment: @SteliosK, I just added the link at the bottom of the post. It is here too: https://imgur.com/a/Q5ZTgR9 -- Thanks...as you can see from the pic, there are divisions that have people in these countries but have other "division" names (aka Segment) However, I want the 3 countries to be called CARS and if it is NOT one of those countries, i want it to spit out the other values I have listed. Many thanks!

Comment: @SirGalatsi so all of these fields are consolidated into one table?

Comment: @SteliosK Yes, sir. It's all on one table.

Comment: @SteliosK -- after further review and a mistake on my part, your logic works perfectly. :) Thanks so much!

Comment: @SirGalatsi great! I am glad you were able to get what you needed. Can you please accept my answer?